# Deriving the Path Integral Representation of the Fokker-Planck Equation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, path-integral, stochastic-processes

Suppose $$dX_t = \mu(X_t,t)dt + \sigma(X_t,t)dW_t$$ is a 1D nonlinear stochastic differential equation ($dW_t$ is typically assumed to be Brownian). According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation) the distribution of $X_t$ at any instant obeys
$$
\frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial t} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\mu(x,t) p(x,t)) + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(D(x,t)p(x,t)).
$$

which is known as the Fokker-Planck equation (in 1D). I'm interested in developing this into a path integral. Some sketches are given at the bottom of the wiki page, but it's very difficult to understand them. Is there a standard reference here? There is one on the page, but it is rather specific to critical phenomena.

Comment: Related Math.SE question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2424787/11127 Related Phys.SE question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55288/2451

Comment: Thanks, @Qmechanic. I actually ended up solving my problem using the technique of Chow and Buice: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4385267/.